# Receive more spam emails

Tags: spam, honeypot

Out of curiosity I want my email address to receive as much spam as possible.

For this, I have already set up a virtual machine, with a Postfix that has a catch-all user, so I receive every email to my domain.

These are the things I have done so far:

- I've put some emails on my website with a font size of 0px, so a normal user would not see it, so it can be scraped.
- Put it on Pastebin
- Put it on social media accounts
- Put it on GitHub
- I've also used unsubscribe forms on sketchy websites, as well as subscribe forms to newsletters, but never clicked the confirm link, with the intention that the e-mail is sold somehow.

For everything, I have used another email address, so I can trace where I had put it initially.

I haven't had much success so far, who would've thought luring spammers is such a hard task. Although I think one must sow a lot and it takes time and patience to reap.

Does anybody have another idea to get more spam? In other words, have my email put on the spammers mailing list?